# How to use multiple whereIn in Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a collection of arrays that I'm trying to return based on the `$prices` value that I passed in.
$prices = ['100', '200'];

```
 $collection = collect([
   ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100, 'price2' => 150],
   ['product' => 'Chair', 'price' => 150, 'price2' => 200],
   ['product' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 300, 'price2' => 350],
   ['product' => 'Door', 'price' => 400, 'price2' => 200],
   ['product' => 'Door', 'price' => 450, 'price2' => 500],
 ]);

 $filtered = $collection->whereIn('price', $prices)->whereIn('price2', $prices);

 $filtered->all();

/* The result should return where price or price2 is 100 or 200:
  [
    ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100, 'price2' => 150],
    ['product' => 'Chair', 'price' => 150, 'price2' => 200],
    ['product' => 'Door', 'price' => 400, 'price2' => 200],
  ]
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use collection `filter` instead of whereIn :

```
$prices = ['100', '200'];
$collection = collect([
    ['product' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100, 'price2' => 150],
    ['product' => 'Chair', 'price' => 150, 'price2' => 200],
    ['product' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 300, 'price2' => 350],
    ['product' => 'Door', 'price' => 400, 'price2' => 200],
    ['product' => 'Door', 'price' => 450, 'price2' => 500],
]);
    
$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($prices) {
    return (in_array($value['price'], $prices) || in_array($value['price2'], $prices)) ? true : false ;
});
$filtered->all();
```

Comment: Thank you Aulia. It is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can use wherebetween to get a data within a price range.

```
$filtered = $collection->whereBetween('price', [100, 200]);

$filtered->all();
```